# Jqgrid Complex Search

Tags: search, jqgrid, grid

Here is the Scenario i have a JQGrid requesting a full data list from a service, i have used the complex search and it was working very good with this attribute loadonce: true;

```
gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 20,
    scroll: 0,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 50, 100, 1000],
    sortname: 'ID',
    pager: '#pager',
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    autowidth: true,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    scrollOffset: 0,
    loadonce: false,
    ignoreCase: true,
```

if i disable the loadonce to false then the complex search will not work, what really i want on how to search the existing records that has been already loaded, lets say i have 1000 row loaded; i need to filter them internally without sending data to the server, any idea ?

Extra information for search

```
 {
        multipleSearch: true,
         multipleGroup: false, 
         showQuery: false,
         odata: ['contains', 'equal', 'not equal', 'less', 'less or equal', 'greater', 'greater or equal', 'begins with', 'does not begin with', 'is in', 'is not in', 'ends with', 'does not end with', 'does not contain'],
         groupOps: [{ op: "AND", text: "all" }, { op: "OR", text: "any"}],
         matchText: "    Find",
         rulesText: " matches",
         sopt: ['cn', 'bw', 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'ew']

 });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Again i found the answer here by @Oleg, Thanks Oleg

$('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');